# How scrapy yield request.follow actually works

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm unable to figure out the working process of yield in

`yield request.follow(url, callback=func)`

So far I know, the request is sent and response is sent to the callback function and finally, a request object is returned which is yield. For Example, the below code gets a response and further extracts the links from it, and sends the request.

```py
def parse_foo(self, response):
    foo_links = response.css(self.some_css['foo_links']).extract()

    for link in foo_links:
        yield response.follow(link, self.add_foo, meta={'foo_items': self.foo_items})
    yield self.load_product_items(response, request.meta['foo_items'])
```

**What Should Code Do:**
For each link in foo_links(in line-4), in the first iteration request should be sent on link 1, the response should go in `self.add_foo` function which will return an item, and code will save that in meta. Finally, the same request will be yield and the next iteration of the loop is started.

**What Actually Happens:**
In the first iteration, the request is sent and all process is done and request is yield but, unexpectedly, the loop breaks and curser goes to the first line which means it starts processing next response and so on.

I am unable to understand this behavior. On the other hand, if I don't use yield then the program behaves normally like iterates the entire loop and steps toward the last two lines to yield the actual final result.

Comment: [`response.follow`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-for-creating-requests) is just a shortcut for creating `Request`s (works with relative URLs, can extract links from `Selector`s itself etc.). Please post actual code and not some pseudo-code, it's hard to follow.

Comment: Check the edited one now.

Comment: see [scrapy.http.TextResponse.follow](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.follow)